# Error after Upgrading to Spartacus 3.0 from 2.0, TypeError: Cannot read property 'findStores' of undefined

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am getting the below error after upgrading to Spartacus 3.0 from 2.0. everything else is working fine but getting this error. I have added storefinder module following the steps provided by SAP team in doc site

[image]

spartacus-core.js >>
[image]

spartacus-core.js >>
[image]

Comment: Could you add the a screenshot containing the details of `spartacus-core.js:1698` and `spartacus-storefinder-core.js:162`? Also which exact version are you running? Do you have custom code in your project?

Comment: I am using spartacus 3.3.0 and upgraded from 2.0.0,

Comment: @LTiger : I have attached the snaps above please find it

Comment: @AnujSharma @LTiger did you have a chance to fix this issue? I'm also facing it (checked on version 3.3.2 and 3.2.0).
Might it be related to lazy loaded store finder, when on PDP we're using `StoreFinderService` ?

Comment: This error occurs only on fresh non store-finder (ie PDP) page load, if you open store-finder first, and then navigate to PDP - no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's due to the usage of `StoreFinderService` on the page when the  `StoreFinderModule` is not loaded (in my case it was PDP).
Store finder is lazy loaded in our (and the default) setup, hence not loaded on PDP (on fresh page load).
In order to make it working the service should be pre-loaded instead of injecting, for example:

```
private storeFinderService: Observable<StoreFinderService> = this.unifiedInjector
    ? (this.unifiedInjector
        .get(StoreFinderService)
        .pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })) as Observable<StoreFinderService>)
    : of();
```

and then use it in your component/service like below:

```
this.storeFinderService
      .pipe(
        map((service) =>
          // do your logic
        )
      )
      .subscribe(); // don't forget to unsubscribe in component
```

See the original Spartacus code fragment as a reference (how to use `UnifiedInjector` to access not (lazy) loaded yet code):
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/cms/facade/page-meta.service.ts#L27